# Adding metadata to video file

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, metadata

I have been scratching my head for a while now, so I'm hoping someone out there can help.

I'm trying to add some metadata to a videofile that I pick from the photo library, and then upload to a server. I want to be able to set stuff like who filmed it and a description. There is a few questions about it here on SO but they did not make me any closer to a solution, also the apple documentation on the subject was very confusing.

So, could anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

My plan-b is to upload a JSON file along with the video containing the metadata, but this will be a hassle for the guys doing the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could use **ffmpeg**, you can try this [example from the docs](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/FFmpeg_Metadata):

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile -metadata title="Movie Title" -metadata year="2010" outputfile
```

To check the metadata you could use [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html):

```
ffprobe out.mp4
```

of with the help of [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format out.mp4 | jq ".[].tags"
```

You could try on your desktop and later give a try with FFmpeg libraries for iOS